# Removing an Ajax loader image after sometime

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax loader that appears after a button is clicked with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
{
        $.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function () {
        $.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
        $.getElementById('loading2').style.display = 'block';
        };
    }(document));
});
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="submit" class="button alt"  onclick="$(\'#loading\').show();" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order"/>'
```

I would like the ajax loader to disappear after like 10seconds.

Please let me know

Comment: You can use javascript setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to hide your loader after 10 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loading').hide(); // I wasnt sure which one you wanted to hide
    $('#loading2').hide();
}, 10000);
```

Also looking at your code im not sure if that would have worked anyway. Also if you are using jQuery then you don't really need to use vanilla Javascript so your code could be changed to this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#form').submit(function () {
        $('#submit').css('display', 'block');
        $('#loading2').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
// setTimeout() function will be fired after page is loaded
// it will wait for 10 sec. and then will fire
// $("#successMessage").hide() function

setTimeout(function() {
$("#loading").hide('blind', {}, 500)
}, 10000);
});
```

**Note:** In order to make you jQuery function work inside setTimeout you should wrap it inside

```
function() { ... }
```